# Form validation on ng-click angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to find a solution in the existing answers, hence i am posting this.

I have a form which has many input fields, many of them are required.

There are buttons (more than 2) in the form and are tied to functions in controllers using ng-click.

I need to have form validated on ng-click before the function is executed.

By default, form validation is happening after function execution. Function should not run if required fields are not filled.

I have created a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/z1uyyqg9/

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.name=undefined;
        $scope.preview = function(){
            alert("Previewed");
        };
        $scope.update = function(){
            alert("Updated");
        }
    });
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model='name' required>
        <button ng-click='preview()'>Preview</button>
        <button ng-click='update()'>Update</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Not get your point. Did you mean HTML 5 validation on fields ?

Comment: @Vineet Yeah, HTML 5 validation.

Comment: take a look at angular https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Most often in AngularJS you'll find that it is a common pattern to disable the buttons unless the form is valid.  So, add a form name and then you can just add:  `ng-disabled="myFormName.$invalid"` to your buttons.

Comment: @jme11 That is one option. But since there can be many input and select fields in the form. I wanted to let user know what he is missing on button click instead of him figuring out what he is missing.

Comment: You can use any of the built in directives like ng-messages or ng-class/ng-invalid or ng-style to give feedback to the user if you use novalidate on the form and handle feedback in your app.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A very-very simple solution is to give the form a name so you can refer to it and then tweak the `ng-click` to fire only if the form is valid:

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" ng-model='name' ng-required="true" />
    <button ng-click="myform.$valid && preview()">Preview</button>
    <button ng-click="myform.$valid && update()">Update</button>
</form>
```

Forked fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r8d1uq0L/

I like separating validation (a business concern) from the view, to that end I created [egkyron](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron) that lets you define the model constraints in code and use programmatic validation along with standard Angular form validation.

Comment: That is one option. But since there can be many input and select fields in the form, I wanted to let user know what he is missing on button click instead of him figuring out what he is missing and why button is disabled.

Comment: Display a marker on the invalid fields then? Angular is giving the tools to do it - starting with the `ng-invalid` CSS class.

Comment: Above code doesn't ignore ng-disabled fields. How can i make it ignore ng-disabled fields (even if it has ng-required).

Comment: You will have to repeat the `ng-disabled` condition to the `ng-required`, only negated, as: `<input ... ng-disabled="foo.condition" ng-required="!foo.condition" />`.

Comment: Looks like pain in the back. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 4):

You could set a flag so that you can show some kind of a required message or set some css class when the form is invalid.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name=undefined;
    $scope.showMsgs = false;
    $scope.preview = function(form){
        if ($scope[form].$valid) {
            alert("Previewed");
        } else {
            $scope.showMsgs = true;
        }
    };
    $scope.update = function(form){
        if ($scope[form].$valid) {
            alert("Updated");
        } else {
            $scope.showMsgs = true;
        }    
    };
});
```

```css
.error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form name="myform" novalidate ng-init="disabled=false">
        <p ng-show="showMsgs && myform.name.$error.required">This field is required</p>
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model='name' ng-required="!disabled" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-class="{error: showMsgs && myform.name.$error.required}" />
        
        <button ng-click="preview('myform')">Preview</button>
        <button ng-click="update('myform')">Update</button>
        <button ng-click="disabled=!disabled">toggle disabled</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Above code doesn't ignore ng-disabled fields. How can i make it ignore ng-disabled fields (even if it has ng-required=true).

Comment: Use ng-required on the fields instead of required and set the expression to check if the field is not disabled.  Technically, it has nothing to do with the code above.  Validation is going to fail if something is required and not filled in regardless if it's disabled or not.  Make sense?

Comment: Updated the example, so you can toggle disabled.