# AngularJS - Require input field before running function with ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I need to make sure that users puts a message in a textarea box before they submit the form with ng-click.

Here is the function that is going to run when ng-click is clicked:

```
$scope.reject = function() {
  $http.post( 'http://server.com/api/reject/' + carID, { Message: Message } ).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.output = data;
  })
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="reject" class="animated">
  <h3>WARNING</h3>
  <p>Your are about to <strong><u>REJECT</u></strong> this CAR. Are you sure this is the action that you want to take?</p>
  <form name="reject">
    <textarea placeholder="Message" ng-model="Message" ng-required="true"></textarea>
    <button ng-click="reject.$valid && reject()">Reject</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

My HTML ng-click code it got from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159006/form-validation-on-ng-click-angularjs):

```
<form name="myform">
  <input type="text" ng-model='name' ng-required="true" />
  <button ng-click="myform.$valid && preview()">Preview</button>
  <button ng-click="myform.$valid && update()">Update</button>
</form>
```

But for some reason this doesn't work for me. If I remove `forward.$valid &&` and just have it as `ng-click="reject()` it runs just fine although I can still run it without putting in a message. I need the textarea to be required. So I need to validate before the function runs. The snippet I got off the other post should work but I don't know why it isnt.

**EDIT** - Here is a fiddle: [My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8d1uq0L/224/)

Now the message box is mine and the other one below that is someone else's working fiddle. I don't see why mine isn't working.

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't the `reject.$valid` be false because the form is not valid if the <textarea> is not populated. It would be invalid because it is `ng-required`. Therefore, the function will not run.

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue in plunkr/fiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/r8d1uq0L/224 ........Now the message box is mine and the other one below that is someone else's working fiddle. I don't see why mine isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stuck a console.info into your working preview function and found that your reject value on the $scope is registering as a constructor. I can only guess that you have found a keyword. I changed the name of the function to reject2 and it appeared as a function and runs the alert you requested. Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nodirtyrockstar/r8d1uq0L/226/)

```
$scope.reject2 = function() {
    alert("hi");
  }
ng-click="reject.$valid && reject2()
```

## Update

Sorry I shared your fiddle link the first time. It is updated now.

Comment: Ya that worked I didn't realize the form name and function name needed to be different. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `reject` to something else in `<form>` and `ng-click` and anywhere else. It is a protected keyword.

Comment: Thats not it at all. https://jsfiddle.net/r8d1uq0L/225/ changed it in this fiddle at it still does not work.

Comment: @agon024 Don't name the form and the function the same thing. This is the underlying problem. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2wapacx8/)'s the proof.